# Integration with substitution of trig: $\int\frac1{(x^2-4)^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac1{(x^2-4)^{3/2}}dx $$

I'm unsure how to go about this integral after subbing $x=2\cosh(\theta)$; to the power of $3/2$ is confusing me when trying to simplify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply
$$
\cosh^2 u-\sinh^2 u=1
$$ by setting $$x:=2\cosh u,\qquad (x\geq2),$$ giving
$$
(x^2-4)^{3/2}=(4\cosh^2 u-4)^{3/2}=8\left(\sinh^2 u\right)^{3/2}=8\sinh^3 u.
$$ Then

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int\frac1{(x^2-4)^{3/2}}dx&=\int\frac{2\sinh u}{8\sinh^3 u}du\\\\
> &=\frac14\int\frac{1}{\sinh^2 u}du\\\\
> &=-\frac14\coth u+C\\\\
> &=-\frac{x}{4 \sqrt{x^2-4}}+C.
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: What do you do to coth to take it to the next step, u=arccosh(x/2)?

Comment: @James I write $$\coth u=\frac{\cosh u}{\sinh u}=\frac{2\cosh u}{2\sinh u}=\frac{x}{2(\cosh^2 u-1)^{1/2}}=\frac{x}{(x^2-4)^{1/2}}$$

Comment: Ah thanks, massive help

Answer (score 0):

Let $u^2x^2=x^2-4$. Then $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-4}{u^2-1}}$, $dx=\pm(-4)\sqrt{\frac{u^2-1}{-16}}\left(\frac{-2u}{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}\right)\,du$.

$$\int\frac{1}{\left(x^2-4\right)^{3/2}}\, dx=\int\frac{\pm(-4)\sqrt{\frac{u^2-1}{-16}}\left(\frac{-2u}{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}\right)\,du}{u^3\cdot \pm\left(\frac{-4}{u^2-1}\right)\sqrt{\frac{-4}{u^2-1}}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{u^2}\, du=\frac{x}{-4\sqrt{x^2-4}}+C$$